# Play a sound via javascript event in iOS 5 HTML5 app

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile-safari, ios5

Developing an HTML 5 application on new iPad's Mobile Safari iOS 5 that displays a user prompt when a "dispatch" is received. To bring attention to the user, we have a sound that plays like this when a alert function is called:

```
snd.src = snd.src;
snd.play();
```

Unfortunately, Apple changed the methodology for playing sounds. Does anyone know if there are updates in iOS 5 that fixes this?

*Did a lot of research and already aware that the old "hack" in iOS 3 no longer works.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The sounds require user input in iOS5. You can initialize the sound with an "invisible" button that disappears after one press at the initialization of your app. Once triggered, you should be able to call `snd.play()` programatically. It's kind of a cheat, but hopefully it helps!

Javascript:

```
if((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i))) {

    document.write('<a id="init" ontouchstart="javascript:sndInit();"></a>');

    function sndInit(){
    snd.play();
    snd.pause();
    document.getElementById('init').style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

CSS:

```
<style>
    #init {
        position: absolute;
        margin-right: 0px;
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
        z-index: 1000;
    }
</style>
```

Also, Remy Sharp has some tips on working with audio sprites [HERE](http://remysharp.com/2010/12/23/audio-sprites/).

Comment: I've posted a demo of this on jsfiddle - it's not working yet, because `snd.src` isn't defined yet. Would there be any way to get this example to work properly? http://jsfiddle.net/esn8C/

Comment: This example was just a work-around for iOS's user-input requirement. I'd recommend checking out http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/introduction-to-the-html5-audio-tag-javascript-manipulation/ for a great introduction to controlling HTML5 audio with javascript.