# How to play sounds in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ios, audio

I have the following:

```
<audio id="clickdown-wav" src="ClickDown.wav" preload="auto"></audio>
```

and then in my JavaScript, I have:

```
var ClickDown = $('#clickdown-wav')[0];

$(document).delegate('a','click',function() {
    ClickDown.play();
});
```

The problem is that it's not too snappy (on an iPad) as I press anchor tags.  There is a noticeable lag between the time I press the anchor tag and the wav file plays.

Q: Is there a source code only solution to playing sounds from JavaScript?
Clickdown.wav is only 1k.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On iOS, there is no preloading.  This was done by Apple on purpose, so that the user wouldn't have to use unnecessary bandwidth.

Comment: It's always something, isn't it?

Comment: A workaround would be to trigger load() on a user event (click, scroll, etc).

Comment: Possibly, but @cf_PhillipSenn's phrasing seems to implicate *every* bound `a click` event, not just the first one.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to place an invisible "button" over your web app, which get's click with the first user interaction. After that interaction `sound.play();` should work. Look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856502/play-a-sound-via-javascript-event-in-ios-5-html5-app).

Answer (score 1):

you need to use touch events not click events, switch your click to "touchstart" and the delay will disappear