# How does this site play a .MP3 in-browser on iOS without it exiting the browser to play the file iOS's native quicktime player?

Tags: ios, mp3, native, quicktime

http://www.giantbomb.com/podcasts/

You can play their podcast MP3 files (by hitting "Play", naturally) and you don't get tossed over to a Quicktime player like you do when you normally click on MP3 files on iOS.

I thought this might be done via the HTML5 `<audio>` tag but based on the page source it doesn't appear so.

Does anybody know how they do it?

Answer (score 0):

It's done via Javascript. I don't know a lot about the implementation details as I'm not very familiar with JS, but if you inspect the source of the site you linked to, you'll find a file titled MediaPlayer.js. Within this you'll find all the source for the player, the important part of which is the call to play();

You can find more info here: [Play a sound via javascript event in iOS 5 HTML5 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856502/play-a-sound-via-javascript-event-in-ios-5-html5-app)